# How do I check if all fields of a struct are NULL?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to check if all fields in my BigQuery struct (`RECORD` type, not repeated) are NULL. Using `struct_column IS NULL` doesn't work, as it returns `false` even if all the fields in `struct_column` are NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Whole struct being NULL is semantically different from all its fields being NULL, you have to check field by field.

```sql
create temp function all_fields_is_null(s struct<x int64, y int64>) 
as (s.x is null and s.y is null);

select 
 all_fields_is_null((null, null)),
 all_fields_is_null((1, null)),
 all_fields_is_null((1, 1));
```

Output:

```
+------+-------+-------+
| f0_  |  f1_  |  f2_  |
+------+-------+-------+
| true | false | false |
+------+-------+-------+
```